# AgoraClassroomSDK Not allowing to Show Teacher in Full Page & showing in Thumbnail just same like Students

Tags: ios, swift, agora.io, agora, agora-implementation

I am working on online Teaching Video Class Integration on which I have used Agora SDK.

So the requirement is very clear, I have 2 different users called Student & Teacher.

So while Launching Student App we need to make sure that All students who joined lecture should show in thumbnail & Teacher should show in Full Screen Video Mode.

But right now the issue is Teacher it self also showing in thumbnail mode on top of the application.

Here is my Student App Video Part Integration :

```
func launchAgora(uuid: String , token: String)
{
    let appId = DATA_CONSTANT.appAgoraId  // Your app ID
    let rtmToken = token  // Your signaling token
    let userUuid = uuid  // Your user ID
    let class_type = Int(DATA_CONSTANT.dicAgoraMeetingClassData?.class_type ?? "4") ?? 4
    let mediaOptions = AgoraEduMediaOptions(encryptionConfig: nil, videoEncoderConfig: nil, latencyLevel: .ultraLow, videoState: .on, audioState: .on)

    let launchConfig = AgoraEduLaunchConfig(userName: "\(DATA_CONSTANT.dicuserData?.first_name ?? "") \(DATA_CONSTANT.dicuserData?.last_name ?? "")",  // The user name
                                                userUuid: userUuid,  // The user ID
                                                userRole: .student,  // The user role
                                            roomName: DATA_CONSTANT.dicAgoraMeetingClassData?.roomnaame ?? "",  // The room name
                                            roomUuid: DATA_CONSTANT.dicAgoraMeetingClassData?.roomid ?? "",  // The room ID
                                            roomType: AgoraEduRoomType(rawValue: class_type) ?? .small,  // The room type, 0: One-to-one interactive teaching, 2: Big class, 4: Online interactive small class
                                                appId: appId, token: rtmToken,
                                                startTime: nil,  // The starting time of the class
                                                duration: NSNumber(value: 7200),  // The class duration
                                                region: AgoraEduRegion(rawValue: 3) ?? .AP,  // The area
                                                mediaOptions: mediaOptions,  // Media stream related settings
                                                userProperties: nil)  // User properties defined by the developer
    AgoraClassroomSDK.setDelegate(self)
    AgoraClassroomSDK.launch(launchConfig, success: launchSuccessBlock, failure: failureBlock)
}
```

Kindly help me out to get it resolved.

Any Help or suggestions will be Highly Appreciated.

Comment: i guess you need to use  join channel when usertype = teacher, rather then same student code

var channelName = "default"

func joinChannel() {
    localVideoView.isHidden = false

    getAgoraEngine().joinChannel(byToken: tempToken, channelId: channelName, info: nil, uid: userID) { [weak self] (sid, uid, elapsed) in
        self?.userID = uid
    }    
}
https://medium.com/agora-io/building-a-1-to-many-ios-video-app-with-agora-7ffe5b7abc79